# iOS 5.1 simulator stopped working after upgrade to Xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode4, ios-simulator, xcode4.3

I can no longer run my app in the simulatore once I migrated to XCode 4.3 (Version 4.3.1 (4E1019)). Every time I start it I'm getting the following in my console log. Any idea how to fix this?

```
    Mar 17 15:20:43 mymacbookpro root: Application Launched: bundle_id: com.apple.iphonesimulator version: 272.21 path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.assetsd): Unknown value for key POSIXSpawnType: Interactive
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.BTServer): Unknown key for boolean: HopefullyExitsFirst
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.calaccessd): Unknown value for key POSIXSpawnType: Interactive
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.dataaccess.dataaccessd): Unknown value for key POSIXSpawnType: Interactive
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.gamed): Unknown value for key POSIXSpawnType: Interactive
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.geod): Unknown value for key POSIXSpawnType: Interactive
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.itunescloudd): Unknown value for key POSIXSpawnType: Interactive
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.itunesstored): Unknown value for key POSIXSpawnType: Interactive
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.locationd): Unknown value for key POSIXSpawnType: Interactive
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.lsd): Unknown value for key POSIXSpawnType: Interactive
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.managedconfiguration.profiled): Unknown value for key POSIXSpawnType: Interactive
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.marcoagent): Conflict with job: com.apple.marcoagent over Mach service: com.apple.marco
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.mediaremoted): Unknown value for key POSIXSpawnType: Interactive
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.mobile.installd): Unknown value for key POSIXSpawnType: Interactive
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.searchd): Unknown value for key POSIXSpawnType: Interactive
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.securityd): Unknown value for key POSIXSpawnType: Interactive
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.syncdefaultsd): Conflict with job: com.apple.syncdefaultsd over Mach service: com.apple.syncdefaultsd
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.syncdefaultsd): Conflict with job: com.apple.syncdefaultsd over Mach service: com.apple.syncdefaultsd.push
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.UIKit.pasteboardd): Unknown value for key POSIXSpawnType: Interactive
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.ubd): Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:5193 (25397):2
    Mar 17 15:20:44 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.ubd): Path monitoring failed on "/Users/me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Library/Application Support/Ubiquity/ubiquity.keepalive": No such file or directory
    Mar 17 15:20:45 mymacbookpro com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.locationd[29365]: Can't open BayesianFilter model file
    Mar 17 15:20:45 mymacbookpro com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.locationd[29365]: Input posteriorThresholds has wrong size.
    Mar 17 15:20:45 mymacbookpro com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.locationd[29365]: NOTICE,Location icon should now be in state 0
    Mar 17 15:20:47 mymacbookpro installd[29375]: ac2bd2c0 load_application_type: Could not extract identifier for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk//Applications/iOS Diagnostics.app
    Mar 17 15:20:47 mymacbookpro installd[29375]: ac2bd2c0 load_application_type: Could not extract identifier for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk//Applications/Photo Booth.app
    Mar 17 15:20:49 mymacbookpro com.apple.launchd.peruser.72056[276] (com.apple.iPhoneSimulator:com.apple.locationd[29365]): Exited with code: 1
    Mar 17 15:20:49 mymacbookpro Xcode[28566]: Error launching simulated application: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=1 "The simulated application quit." UserInfo=0x4044930a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The simulated application quit., DTiPhoneSimulatorUnderlyingErrorCodeKey=-1}
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app
    Mar 17 15:21:52 mymacbookpro root: Application Quit: bundle_id: com.apple.iphonesimulator version: 272.21 path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app

    3/17/12 3:21:51.266 PM iPhone Simulator: *** Assertion failure in -[NSEvent pressure], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1138.32/AppKit.subproj/NSEvent.m:1491
    3/17/12 3:21:51.267 PM iPhone Simulator: Invalid message sent to event "NSEvent: type=MouseExited loc=(231.117,548.988) time=214571.3 flags=0x100 win=0x17e510 winNum=19479 ctxt=0x1f60b evNum=7058 trackNum=3b5c00 userData=0x0"
    3/17/12 3:21:51.268 PM iPhone Simulator: (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x9718bb67 __raiseError + 231
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x948f1149 objc_exception_throw + 155
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x970f3369 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 137
        3   Foundation                          0x94ea3267 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
        4   AppKit                              0x92c7828a -[NSEvent pressure] + 200
        5   iPhone Simulator                    0x0000ec2e iPhone Simulator + 56366
        6   AppKit                              0x92b32a57 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 7204
        7   AppKit                              0x92ac36d5 -[NSApplication run] + 1007
        8   AppKit                              0x92d57261 NSApplicationMain + 1054
        9   iPhone Simulator                    0x000027b5 iPhone Simulator + 6069
    )
```